# How to align equal spacing for 2 divs

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, bootstrap-modal

Say for example if I have two texts in two divs, which are currently have equal widths. However, the text on the left must be left aligned and the text on the right must be center aligned. But this inadvertently causes the spacing between the left edge and the left text to be smaller than the spacing between the right edge and the right text. How do I ensure that there is equal spacing on both sides?

[image depicting situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQq3x.png)

css

```
.ll {
    position: relative;
    left:0px;
    background-color: brown;
    
}

.rr {
    position: relative;
    left:10px;
    background-color: green;
    
    float: right;
    
}

.left {
    background-color: red;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15%;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

.right {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15%;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

.outside {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container outside"  >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="ll">
                  <p>This is the LEFT text. <br> This is the LEFT text. <br> This is the LEFT text. <br> This is the LEFT text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="right">
                <div class="rr">
                    <p>This is the RIGHT text. <br> This is the RIGHT text. <br> This is the RIGHT text. <br>This is the RIGHT text. <br>
                        This is the RIGHT text. <br> This is the RIGHT text. <br> This is the RIGHT text. <br>This is the RIGHT text. <br> 
                        This is the RIGHT text.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pepega/41fh98xs/

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *As you updated your question; removing `float:right` from your `.rr` class will solve your problem.*

**Original**

Have you coded an example?

For future questions, please try to do some coding yourself, and if it doesn't work, show us the code you tried. This really helps us understand the question, and we might even save some time.

If I got your question correct, you want a page like the image you showed, but it needs to be inside the container?

This is done by adding `text-align:left|center|right` to the element. I made an example below.

**CSS**

```css
.container{
  max-width:900px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.box{
  width:40%;
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
.space-between { 
  justify-content: space-between; 
}  
.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container space-between">
    <div class="box">
      I will not call my teacher "Hot Cakes".
  </div>
  <div class="box text-center">
      I will not pledge allegiance to Bart.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example looks just exactly like your photo, but it's inside it's containers width.
Is this what you were looking for?

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/asowr8yp/4/)

[Read about Flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: hi thank you for your response, i have tried it out myself and updated the question. What I meant was the spacing between the text and the edge of the page should be the same, i.e. the left text should be relative to the left edge by the same amount of spacing as the right scenario

Comment: Would you mind marking it as correct? If it helped you solve the issue :D